# Interpreting the bit pattern of FLT_MAX

Tags: floating-point

`FLT_MAX` has a bit pattern of `01111111011111111111111111111111`.

If I understand correctly, such a bit pattern should represent `1.111...1 * 2^128` (with twenty-three 1's after the decimal). However, the actual value of `FLT_MAX` is just `1.0 * 2^128`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exponent is wrong, it's `1.111...1 * 2^127 = 2^128 - 2^104`. That is pretty close (relatively) to `2^128`, and you need to print it out with more than default precision in C or C++ to see the difference (note, as a `float` - if that is an IEEE754 32-bit `float` - `2^128` is infinity, so you need a `double`).

The bit pattern yields

```
  0   11111110  11111111111111111111111
  ^      ^             ^
sign  exponent     mantissa
       254-127     2 - 2^(-23)
```

Printing the full values:

```
340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0   // FLT_MAX
340282366920938463463374607431768211456.0   // 2^128
```

you can see the difference at the eighth digit.